# JQUERY foreach appending PHP script out of order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax function that loads a php script for each item in an array and then appends it to an html tag. The issue is that the scripts are appending out of order. How do I preserve the order of the objects?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.getJSON('apiUrl.com', function(response) {
    $.each(response.data, function(key, val) {
      $.get("phpFile.php", {
        id: val.id,
        title: val.title,
        img_url: val.images.jpg.image_url
      }, function(html) {
        $("#elementToLoadPhpFile").append(html);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: *"Out of order"* implies some sort of sort order? The response *will always be* however the data was formed from the server. So, what is the "sort order" you desire? What is your server-side code returning in terms of "sort order"?

Comment: Ahh, this is AJAX so client side may not render in same order you prefer, due to the 2nd ajax call. I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `$.get` requests are being called in parallel. This results in a *race* condition where the order is not maintained. Think of it as **first come, first served**.

To preserve the order wrap each request in a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and collect all these promises in a single array. Pass the array to [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all requests to finish.

Whenever all requests are done you'll get an array which has the same order in which all requests are made. Loop over this array to append the values of each request to the page.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.getJSON('apiUrl.com', function(response) {
    const requests = response.data.map(val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.get("phpFile.php", {
        id: val.id,
        title: val.title,
        img_url: val.images.jpg.image_url
      })
      .done(html => resolve(html))
      .fail((xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) => reject(errorThrown));
    }));

    Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {
      responses.forEach(html => {
        $("#elementToLoadPhpFile").append(html);
      });
    });
  });
});
```